# Blazor isolation not working for some elements

Tags: css, bootstrap-4, sass, blazor, blazor-server-side

I'm using SCSS to build my CSS files directly in Visual Studio. One file might look like:

```
//Variable overrides
$white: white;
$sidebar-dark-bg: $white;
$sidebar-dark-color: $white;
$sidebar-dark-submenu-color: #004e86;
$sidebar-dark-submenu-hover-color: $sidebar-dark-submenu-color;

//Bootstrap
@import 'bootstrap/scss/bootstrap';

.container-fluid {
    background-color: red;
    padding-right: 5px !important;
    padding-left: 5px !important;
}

.main-header, .nav-header {
    background: linear-gradient(120deg, #ffd800 65%, #4cff00 65%);
    color: $white;
}
```

I have one particular razor file (component not page) using css isolation and in order to test style overrides in media breakpoints I did:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 576px) {
    .container-fluid {
        background-color: blue;
        width: 100%;
    }

    .main-header, .nav-header {
        background: linear-gradient(120deg, #ffd800 65%, #4cff00 65%);
        color: $black;
    }
}
```

However, the above is not working. The appearance stays the same and the elements' styles are not being overridden. I'm not seeing them in chrome's developer console either.

Styles created in the css isolation file and overridden in the media breakpoints do work as expected.

Is this a known issue and how can it be solved?

Comment: Please specify if the HTML markup containing the container-fluid class and its corresponding media query are on the same (isolated) or in a different component.

Comment: They are contained in the main layout file (inheriting from LayoutComponentBase).